# Replacing old mic with new mic (Rode Wireless Pro) on Mackie mixer - volume is incredibly low on Rode?

Tags: mixing, live, beginner, rode

I'm trying to connect a new microphone to an pre-existing mixer setup for a meeting room, and the volume is incredibly low no matter what I've tried.

Photo of the existing setup:

[image]

The mixer is a [Mackie Mix5](https://mackie.com/en/products/mixers/mix-series/mix5.html).

The old microphone is a [StadiumPro AIR1PRO](https://tdj.com.au/firmware/Stadium/AIR1PRO/AIR1PRO-Manual.pdf)

There are two of these currently, and they are plugged into the Line 2/3 (L channel) and Line 4/5 (L channel) of the mixer.

The new microphone is a [Rode Wireless Pro](https://rode.com/en/microphones/wireless/wirelesspro).

I plugged in the Rode wireless RX is plugged into the L channel for Line 4/5 (using a 3.5mm-to-1/4" converter).

The speaker is a [Bose S1 Pro](https://www.bose.com.au/en_au/products/speakers/portable_pa_speakers/s1_pro_system.html)

For output routing:

- L channel for Main Out is connected to a computer's mic-input (for video calls to that meeting room)
- Phones output is connected to the speaker.

The existing AIR1Pro microphones have sufficient volume - however, the Rode Wireless Pro is incredibly soft even at maximum. I've tried setting the Rode's gain mode to manual and maxed out the level there (very soft), and also to headphone output, and maxed out the level there (still very soft).

Does anybody have any ideas on what the issue is, or what I'm doing wrong?

Or are there any issues with the existing setup?

Comment: As far as I can understand, the RX outputs two channels on it's 3.5 jack. Depending on the way your 3.5 to 6.35 is cabled, you might be adding two signals to the mono 6.35. (Or is the 6.35 a 3 point one ? And the 3.5 ?).

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised you are hearing anything at all.

The inputs you have here are *balanced* line inputs. The 3.5mm output of the wireless is an *unbalanced* output with identical signals left and right.  With a straightforward 6.3mm to 3.5mm adapter, both hot/cold of the balanced input will get the same signal, and the mixer is supposed to subtract them for the final results.  What you hear is the error in subtraction, what remains after common mode suppression.

You need a 3.5mm stereo (TRS) to 6.3mm mono adapter (TS) here, where both T and R of the 3.5mm socket are connected to T in the 6.3mm plug (and, of course, S connects with S).  This "unbalances" the 6.3mm socket of the mixer.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting the Wireless Pro output to channel 1 instead of 4. Then you can use the gain control on channel 1 to increase the level.